# Run the ipython notebook from centos server to windows browser

Tags: ipython

I have installed a virtual `centos 7.3` server on my `windows` machine. And on centos server i have installed ipython notebook, by using `pip`

I have browser installed on my `same windows machine`.

When i'm trying to run the `ipython notebook` from centos server using the command `ipython notebook --allow-root`

It is giving me the link something like:

`http://localhost:8888/?token=eaa9719ae6456b5d56fd419208a849b1886d8003051714`

and i'm pasting this link to browser, then i'm getting the warning as not able to connect.

I'm new to ipython, so it would be really helpful if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

After, lot of searching, i just tried unblocking the firewall, and yeah it worked.

I followed the below steps:

- Check the status of firewall `systemctl status firewalld`
- Disabling the firewall `systemctl disable firewalld`
- stop the firewall `systemctl stop firewalld`

and yeah, it worked.